# drawing a line on an image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to draw a line and show it.
assume I have a PIL image.

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pilImage)
draw.line((100,200, 150,300), fill=128)
```

How can I show the image?  Before drawing the line I could do:

```
imshow(pilImage)
```

but `imshow(draw)` does not show the image.

How do I convert this back to a PIL image?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This should work:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 400), (0, 255, 0, 255)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
draw.line((100,200, 150,300), fill=128)
im.show()
```

Basically using `ImageDraw` draw over the image, then display that image after changes, to draw a thick line pass width

```
draw.line((100,200, 150, 300), fill=128, width=3)
```

Comment: great. Might I also ask how can I draw a line with  a weight of more than one pixel?

Comment: @Eran_Id I couldn't find how to set thickness but you can draw thick lines using polygons

Comment: It looks like you can draw a thick line using the "width" option. Similar to how the "fill" option is being used here.

Comment: I enter EXACTLY in the format you suggest and the documentation lists, draw.line((0,0,0,2400), fill = grid_val*255, width = 1), and the system throws "SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple". It absolutely refuses to plot a line.

Comment: draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
             (right, top), (left, top)], width=3,fill=128) can you say me how this draws line! I am confused

Comment: @Sridharan try it and you will see a line on the image.

Comment: @Elliot I have the exact same issue. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: fill=128 didn't work for me. Try fill='black'.

Comment: ! ! the above does not work, because with "RGBA" channels, an alpha value must be set (for opacity: alpha value 255) . such as : fill=0x990000FF .  or just use "RGB" format.